# biblatex conflict with showkeys package?

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility, showkeys

For a long time I wondered why `biblatex` did not typeset author names with `\Citeauthor` in upper case, until I finally could isolate the problem:

When the `showkeys` package is loaded, the name "von Beethoven" will be printed in lower case, even when using `\Citeauthor`, which should print it upper case.
As soon as `showkeys` is disabled, it works perfectly well (the order of loading of both packages does not seem to matter), see example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib4.bib}

@MISC{Volkmann,
  author = {Volkmann, Albert},
  title = {title},
  year = {2005},
}

@MISC{vonBeethoven2005,
  author = {von Beethoven, Ludwig},
  title = {title},
  year = {2005},
}

@MISC{Caesar,
  author = {Caesar, Gaius J.},
  title = {title},
  year = {2005},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[color, draft]{showkeys} %Einblenden der Referenznamen in den Arbeitsversionen
\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{\fbox{\normalfont\tiny\ttfamily#1}} 
\definecolor{refkey}{cmyk}{0.26,0,0.76,0}%{gray}{0.5} 
\definecolor{labelkey}{cmyk}{0.26,0,0.76,0}%{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{grau}{gray}{0.5}

\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8, defernumbers, useprefix, maxnames=99, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}  % fÂ¸r bessere Literaturverzeichnisse
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addsemicolon\space}


\usepackage{csquotes} 

\bibliography{mybib4}

\begin{document}

citeauthor: \citeauthor{vonBeethoven2005} 

Citeauthor: \Citeauthor{vonBeethoven2005}

\cite{vonBeethoven2005}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I would consider a status-by-design on the part of the [`showkeys` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys). Here's why:

Consider the construction of a citation by `showkeys` when in `draft` mode. It does two things, in the following order:

1. Prints the key associated with the BibTeX entry;
2. Typesets the `author` key in the current font.

The order here is important, since the provides two things. Firstly, the construction of the key is layered so that the output generated by `showkeys` could be partially obscured by the regular text. This is apparent when you zoom in on your MWE:

[image]

Note how the "B" of "von Beethoven" is set on top of the key `vonBeethoven2005`. This is captured in the `showkeys` package description:

> ... the ‘internal’ key is printed, without affecting the appearance of the rest of the text, so far as is possible ...

Secondly, if you first typeset the key in a zero-width box with a right overlap (`\rlap`), then you can typeset the actual bib entry text without having to worry about the spacing with regards to subsequent text. Again, using the above example, `vonBeethoven2005` is set wider that "von Beethoven".

The drawback, of course, is that TeX is now asked to capitalize the first letter of the `key`, rather than the `author`, which is incorrect. Moreover, this `key`, since it's raised and "hidden" behind the text, is not set in a easily capitalized form when using `\Citeauthor` from [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).

My suggestion would be to use the `draft` mode during the initial stages of your document, and switch to `final` for the last phase of production. You will most likely so no effect in the output change.

Comment: thanks for your elaborate explanation. I don't have deep knowledge about what happens in TeX, so I'm not sure if I get this right: the reason for the missing capital V is that showkeys modifies the code of the citation and biblatex afterwards tries to capitalize the first letter of a command and not of the real author name?

Comment: Concerning your suggestion: well, now as I know that this problem will be solved as soon as I deactivate showkeys, I'm sleeping much better. :-) The only drawback is: at the moment there are some "mis-spelled" Author names and during proofreading the drafts (printed with showkeys), this will confuse the readers.

Comment: Yes, `showkeys` inserts the `key` *before* setting the actual `author`, making it "difficult" for TeX to capitalize via `\Citeauthor`. It would require rejigging in `showkeys` or some other `showkeys` accommodation within `biblatex` (which would require a load order preference of `showkeys` *then* `biblatex`, say) to correct for this. I'm not that familiar with it, so can't promise a correction. However, you could suggest this to the package author via email, unless someone else comes up with a definitive solution.